# Creating a custom BigDecimal type

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In my application, all BigDecimal numbers are scaled to have two decimal places.. In other words, everytime I create a new BigDecimal in my code, I need to use the method scale too:

```
BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.ZERO;
x.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

So, to minimize the work, I wanted to create my custom BigDecimal type, something like:

```
public class CustomBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {

    public CustomBigDecimal(String val) {
        super(val);
        this.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }

}
```

I know `this.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` doesn't do the job, but I can't find the way to do it, is it possible?

Comment: Why not use a custom type that delegates to the BigDecimal?

Comment: Please note that `x.setScale` doesn't change the scale of `x`, but returns a new BigDecimal object with the same value (possibly rounded) and scale 2. You must assign this to a variable to have any effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a `CustomBigDecimal` that extends from `BigDecimal`. However, as `BigDecimal` is immutable, you would never inherit state (such as the scale and rounding mode) from the parent class.

I'd go for the utility class suggested in another answer, or maybe a wrapper that delegates every operation to an actual `BigDecimal` instance. The downside of this approach is that your brand new `CustomBigDecimal` wouldn't be a `BigDecimal`, so they wouldn't be interchangeable.

EDIT: a downside of this approach is that you have to delegate about 50 methods. Not the end of the world with a good IDE, but definitely not very appealing...

If, after all, you still want to make `CustomBigDecimal` inherit from `BigDecimal`, you'd need to use a *decorator* approach:

```
public class CustomBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {

    private final BigDecimal value;

    private CustomBigDecimal(BigDecimal value) {
        super(value.toPlainString()); // needed to compile, 
                                      // useless except for implicit null-check
        this.value = value;
    }

    public CustomBigDecimal(String val) {
        this(new BigDecimal(val).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }

    @Override
    public CustomBigDecimal abs() {
        return new CustomBigDecimal(this.value.abs());
    }

    // TODO all other methods

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Although i've chosen Danilo Gomes answer to implement in my application, I will set this one as correct since it answers the original question. Thanks to @MarcusWidegren since he suggested this approach too in one of his comments.

Comment: @polska Thanks to you! I also believe Danilo's answer is better than this approach, though I wouldn't use the singleton part. However, I think that @Marcus' approach is the best of all since you don't need to use a context every time you create a new `BigDecimal`. What if you or another developer forget to pass the context argument?

Comment: Hmm.. You're right, we're 2 actually, and I think it would be a lot nicer for the other developer to keep creating BigDecimal's as usual (without a context as param), it's more intuitive and it keeps it simple! Thanks :)

Comment: There are about ~50 methods to delegate. This looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @Marco13 That's why I pointed out that the utility class suggested in another answer was better.

Answer (score 16):

You could simply create a method for yourself that creates a BigDecimal with zero. Something like:

```
public static BigDecimal scaled(String val) {
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(val);
    return x.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

Put it in a helper class, like BigDecimalHelper, BigDecimalFactory or whatever. :)

EDIT: Changed it slightly to return the results of setScale, since BigDecimal is immutable. And to further answer the original question: no what you've written is not possible since the state of the object is not changed with setScale().

Comment: The zero was used as an example.

Comment: @MarcusWidegren Yes, that's a nice way to do it! But I really want to know if there's a way to create that custom BigDecimal type.. Anyway, I'll consider this answer the correct one if no one can help me with the custom type, thanks for answering :)

Comment: It might be possible to subclass it (if BigDecimal is not declared as final, which it probably should be since it's supposed to be immutable), but it won't solve your problem since its state can't change after creation. If you want a custom type, I'd go with one that *has* a BigDecimal instead of *is* one. That way you can create the BigDecimal and change its state, in your constructor. :)

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to create a special type for your use case anyway. E.g. a currency type

Comment: Hm.. If I understood, you're telling me to create a customBigDecimal with a BigDecimal variable inside, correct? @MarcusWidegren

Comment: @polska Yes, if you want a custom type that's what I recommend.

Answer (score 8):

You can store a singleton instance of a MathContext, for instance, and use them as argument to BigDecimal Constructor.

Usually you could do:

```
MathContext context = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(val, context);
```

So, if you have a MathContext as singleton, you can do:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(val, MathInstanceHolder.getMathContext());
```

Where MathInstanceHolder contains a MathContext instance.

Comment: Humbly I prefer this approach instead a wrapper.

I suggested a singleton instance because the value will never change in application scope and will be used for all BigDecimal instances.

This way you can use BigDecimal as always did and the scale will be clear for any other development that read the code.

I just separated the responsibilities but that is subjective.

Suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood your suggestion. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: wow, I really like this approach.. And I agree with you in what you say, the only thing my BigDecimals will have of special is that 2 decimal place, so if I create a singleton as you say, I can use normal BigDecimals as usual and still can set the scale in the constructor.. Awesome, thanks! @DaniloGomes

Comment: Please note that this solution won't work since MathContext precision does not the same as BigDecimal.setScale.

Comment: You say if I change BigDecimal.setScale at other moment?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different and utilize Java 8 - you could also go lambda on the problem:

```
public static Function<String, BigDecimal> SCALED_BIG_DECIMAL = (val) -> new BigDecimal(val).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
...

// and this is how you would use it
SCALED_BIG_DECIMAL.apply("20.2343425")
```