# Java add method to class

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

Good morning, I have a custom class cBigDecimal that extends the class BigDecimal. My goal is to use both the methods from the BigDecimal and cBigDecimal class (for example "add" or "multiply", as well as the custom function "percentage"). The problem is that "add" & co. return BigDecimal, and obviously I can't cast it to cBigDecimal... Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo

Comment: Overload, call super and copy the values to a new cBigDecimal and return a instance of it.

Comment: As @Andy Turner said BigDecimal is immutable, you would never inherit state.  I would suggest to use the decorator pattern e.g. create a private BigDecimal to back your CustomBigDecimal class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969492/creating-a-custom-bigdecimal-type) for a very similar approach/question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly does your `cBigDecimal` class do that a `BigDecimal` doesn't?

It is a design oversight that `BigDecimal` can be extended at all. Josh Bloch says in *Effective Java* 3rd Ed Item 17: "Minimize mutability":

> It was not widely understood that immutable classes had to be effectively final when `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` were written, so all of their methods may be overridden. Unfortunately, this cannot be corrected after the fact while preserving backwards compatibility.

If all you want to do is to "add a method" to `BigDecimal`, you can simply create a helper method:

```
static BigDecimal percent(BigDecimal b) {
  return b.divide(100);  // Or whatever it does.
}
```

Then, you can just deal with plain old `BigDecimal`s everywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to do it in a custom class because it seemed cleaner
`bigDecimalVariable.customMethod()                      //I liked this way
UtilityClass.customMethod(bigDecimalVariable)      //I wanted something shorter`

Anyway, I'll go for the Utility class. Thanks, again ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Basically, you will have to hold an instance of `BigDecimal` in your `CBigDecimal` class as a private member. To create your `CBigDecimal`, you will need an instance of a `BigDecimal` (that could also be `BigDecimal.ZERO`).

Then, in your `CBigDecimal` class you can provide the same interface of `BigDecimal` (you can add a method `CBigDecimal#add(BigDecimal)`), because you have an instance of it in your class, and you are also able to create your own custom methods (as your `CBigDecimal#percentage(double)`).

This is a sample code:

CBigDecimal.java:

```
public class CBigDecimal
{
    private BigDecimal bigDecimal;

    public CBigDecimal(BigDecimal bigDecimal)
    {
        this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
    }

    // This method already exists in BigDecimal class, so it will have the same signature
    public CBigDecimal add(BigDecimal toAdd)
    {
        return new CBigDecimal(bigDecimal.add(toAdd));
    }

    // This is the new method which you will implement as you like
    public CBigDecimal percentage(double percentage)
    {
        BigDecimal multiplied = bigDecimal.multiply(new BigDecimal(percentage));
        BigDecimal total = multiplied.divide(new BigDecimal(100));

        return new CBigDecimal(total);
    }

    // This is another method that already exists in BigDecimal class
    public double doubleValue()
    {
        return bigDecimal.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Then, client code will create an instance of your `CBigDecimal` by providing to its constructor a `BigDecimal` instance.

```
public class CBigDecimalTest
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        CBigDecimal extendedBigDecimal = new CBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(50));

        System.out.println("percentage: " + extendedBigDecimal.percentage(50).doubleValue());
        System.out.println("doubleValue: " + extendedBigDecimal.doubleValue());
     }
}
```

P.S.: this pattern worths it only when you *really* need to extend the BigDecimal class by adding a bunch of new methods. If you simply need to add just a method, it's better to simply declare somewhere a static method as suggested by [Andy Turner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156006/9783898).

Answer (score 0):

## Do not extend `BigDecimal`

The `BigDecimal` class is **not intended to be overridden**. The class should have been marked `final` to enforce this restriction in the compiler, but alas, it was not so marked (an unfortunate oversight). So, do not override `BigDecimal`.

You can read on the rest of my Answer, if thinking of other classes besides `BigDecimal`/`BigInteger`.

## Polymorphism

Learn about *[polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))* in [Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

If you assign a reference to an object of type `Dog` to a variable of type of the superclass `Animal`, and your subclass overrides method `eat`, then calling method `eat` results in the method on the subclass being executed. That is the magic of [late-binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) or [dynamic-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) (various terms for this find-the-right-implementation behavior).

```
Animal x = new Dog( … ) ;   // Polymorphism: Viewing a `Dog` object as an `Animal` object.
x.eat( … ) ;                // Results in Dog::eat method being invoked, *not* Animal::eat.
```

Caveat: Be sure your superclass and its methods are intended to be overridden. If tagged as `final`, they are not.

## Naming

Tip: Follow naming conventions. A class always starts with an uppercase letter. Use `MySubClass`, not `mySubClass` for the class name.

Comment: "Be sure BigDecimal and its methods are intended to be overridden" `BigDecimal` is not intended to be extended: it states that it should be immutable, and immutable classes shouldn't be user-extendable, because then mutability could be added. Josh Bloch talks about how it was a regrettable oversight that the class wasn't declared `final` when it was designed.

Comment: @AndyTurner I recalled as much, but could not look it up at the time of my post. I will update my Answer. Thanks.